# Toad for MySQL Access Denied But Workbench connects fine

Tags: mysql, windows-7, toad

I am trying to use TOAD to connect to a remote mysql server but keep getting access denied for 'user@laptop-hostname'.

Which would make me think that this is a permissions issue except for the fact that I can connect with MYSQL Workbench without problems.

The other weird thing is that I can connect to see the tables and get a list of DBs with TOAD but when I go to do a snapshot or compare I get an access denied error.

Error:

`"SELECT command denied to user 'MY-USER'@'MY-LOCAL-HOSTNAME' for table 'db' Quest.Compare.Schema.MySQl.DBModel`

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I should also mention that I can execute queries fine using TOAD. Seems to be a problem with snapshot and compare.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your user has the required permissions for particular host? See user table for details

Comment: 100% Workbench works fine with that user and password against that host.

Comment: Show full error message.

Comment: I added the error to the question above.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had to fix this myself.  In this case, the DB table toad is referring to is the DB table of the mysql schema.  To fix this, just add a grant permission to MY-USER like so:

```
GRANT SELECT ON 'mysql'.'db' TO 'my-user'@'my-local-hostname';
```

Answer (score 1):

So, error means that you can connect to the server using specified account (MySQL user), but user does not have required privileges.

Try to connect as `root`, and grant SELECT privilege to user 'MY-USER'@'MY-LOCAL-HOSTNAME'. You can grant global-level `SELECT` privilege, database-level or table-level. For example -

```
-- Global level
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'MY-USER'@'my-local-hostname';

-- Database level
GRANT SELECT ON <database_name>.* TO 'MY-USER'@'my-local-hostname';

-- Table level
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE <database_name>.<table_name> TO 'MY-USER'@'my-local-hostname';
```

Then reconnect as 'MY-USER'@'my-local-hostname' again.

Comment: I suspect that you are right here. I will try that out. I was thrown off by the fact that I can SELECT using queries on TOAD but maybe that is a different permission?